# Attempting to append next value of list based on if condition

Tags: python, pandas, list

Background: Hello, I am trying to clean data that I've scraped from a website and stored in a column of a pandas DataFrame called 'raw data'. The use case is for stock data, the ticker symbols are in the same DataFrame under the column name 'Symbol'. Each entry of the raw data is a list that contains 24 elements from volume, to market cap, to prices, etc. My first step is to join these separate elements into a single string. Then I attempt to separate the values into different lists, and will concatenate these lists into a new dataframe.

Issue: The issue I am facing is when I attempt to extract specific elements of my list in order to append them to a new list. Not all of the data fields for each stock symbol populate, so iterating through the list with fixed values does not return the desired results.

Code: This is what I have tried so far.. I know I have probably overcomplicated the steps, and am looking for help troubleshooting. The first few entries in the resulting list are in line with expectation, however; after that the incorrect values are returned:

```
def cleaned_data(df):
    x = df.copy()
    volume = []
    for j,i in enumerate(x['Symbol']):
         for e,vals in enumerate(str(x['raw_data'][j]).split(',')):
                if vals == 'Volume':
                    volume.append([i for e,i in enumerate(str(x['raw_data'][j]).split(',')) if e ==1])
    
    return volume
```

I have tried to only pull volume data from this list first, and then will expand the code to handle the other fields.

The results I am returned with are:

```
[['4.8M'],
 ['2.9M'],
 ['2.5M'],
 ['105.2M'],
 ['14.1M'],
 ['14.1M'],
 ['3.3M'],
 ['11.1M'],
 ['$44.48'],
 ['$50.03'],
 ['$58.37'],
 ['$285.06 - $292.28'],
 ['$267.00 - $270.73'],
 ['$207.67 - $213.41'],
 ['$126.98 - $129.32'],
 ['$51.27 - $52.53'],
 ['$159.88 - $161.10'],
 ['$134.12 - $136.35'],
 ['$212.23 - $216.12'],
 ['$82.55 - $84.37'],
 ['$217.03 - $220.58'],
 ['$17.02 - $17.58'],
 ['$137.00 - $139.06'],
 ['$219.22 - $222.32'],
 ['$137.90 - $139.77'],
 ['$358.76 - $367.49'],
 ['$57.37 - $58.36'],
 ['$212.75 - $216.12'],
 ['$44.62 - $46.47'],
 ['$102.00 - $153.66']]
```

Sample Raw Data =

``````
['Day Range',
 '$285.06 - $292.28',
 '52 Wk Range',
 '$130.85 - $295.89',
 'Market Value',
 '$99.8B',
 'Ytd net Change',
 '10%',
 '1 Yr net Change',
 '19.8%',
 'P/E Ratio(TTM)',
 '16.73',
 'EPS(TTM)',
 '$17.34',
 'Div & Yield',
 '$5.00  (1.72%)',
 'Beta',
 '1.28',
 'Volume',
 '3.8M',
 'Avg Vol (65d)',
 '3.8M',
 'Open',
 '$267.35']

`````

In the above case, volume shows only in the 20th element not the 1st.

I am hoping to iterate through this list and create columns for the pairs of values shown.. i.e(column = Volume, Volume[0] = 4.8M)

Any advice would be really appreciated, thanks!!
``````

Comment: Can you give a sample of the raw data and what you want it to look like?

Comment: yes no problem, I just added a sample of the string created from raw_data

Answer (score 0):

You can map into dataframe columns.  Then you can use `NaN` etc for rows that don't contain certain key/value pairs.   NB this solution does assume key value pairs

```
l = ['Day Range',
 '$285.06 - $292.28',
 '52 Wk Range',
 '$130.85 - $295.89',
 'Market Value',
 '$99.8B',
 'Ytd net Change',
 '10%',
 '1 Yr net Change',
 '19.8%',
 'P/E Ratio(TTM)',
 '16.73',
 'EPS(TTM)',
 '$17.34',
 'Div & Yield',
 '$5.00  (1.72%)',
 'Beta',
 '1.28',
 'Volume',
 '3.8M',
 'Avg Vol (65d)',
 '3.8M',
 'Open',
 '$267.35']
pd.DataFrame([{l[i]:l[i+1] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)}])

df = pd.DataFrame({"symbol":["abcd"],"raw":[l]})
df = pd.json_normalize(
    df.assign(data=lambda dfa: dfa["raw"]
          .apply(lambda l: {l[i]:l[i+1] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)}))
    .to_dict(orient="records")
)
```

### output

```
symbol     data.Day Range   data.52 Wk Range data.Market Value data.Ytd net Change data.1 Yr net Change data.P/E Ratio(TTM) data.EPS(TTM) data.Div & Yield data.Beta data.Volume data.Avg Vol (65d) data.Open
  abcd  $285.06 - $292.28  $130.85 - $295.89            $99.8B                 10%                19.8%               16.73        $17.34   $5.00  (1.72%)      1.28        3.8M               3.8M   $267.35
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response, it's incredibly helpful. I was able to recreate this as you have laid out. However, I'm met with an issue when I try and expand this code to account for every symbol. I have 30 symbols I am trying to iterate through, all with associated raw_data. I created an "l" list as you show above, that holds all of the necessary raw data for each symbol. But when I go to apply the pd.DataFrame step, I am met with a type error since I am trying to iterate through the list which is unhashable, do you have any recommendations to get around this?

Comment: looping over data frames the way you are is inefficient and error prone.  better practice is to get data into named columns then you can always very simply get lists of values without any looping code.